# Disable Modules for specific website in Magento2

Tags: extensions, third-party-module, magento-2.0.7

I am having Multiple stores. I need to Disable some modules for specific website in Magento2.

**Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this**

Comment: Have tried from Stores>Configruation>Advance

Comment: yeah, it will disable only the module output not the controllers,Events those things

Comment: @Nagamani did you manage to solve this issue? I would like to hear how if so. Thanks.

Comment: Still no luck :)